# Simple fix with Throw Catch OO WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, try-catch

**Situation**

I have an issue with a try catch In an OO WPF application I'm developing that allows Members of different types to join Races.

**Problem**

To put my problem in laymans terms, I'm trying to get a Member to join a race with the following code:

```
race.joinJunior((JuniorMember)hillracing.searchMembers(Username));
```

so, a JuniorMember (who's object is found with the searchMember method and a pre-existing Username parameter) will go through the process of joining the race as a Junior member via the joinJunior method.

this code itself is not the problem, but it does cause it, because it calls the joinJunior method and there-in lies my problem.

```
public override void joinJunior(JuniorMember jm)
        {
            if (junior != null)
            {
                //Increment the current members on the race by 1.
                currentRunners++;

                if (currentRunners > limitRace)
                {

                    currentRunners = limitRace;

                    throw new Exception(junior.FirstName + " would be this races: " + limitRace + 1 + "th runner. This race can only take: " + limitRace);


                }
            }
            //if the members type doesnt equal the member join permission then they shouldn't be able to join.
            else if (junior.memType != permRace)
            {
                //throws an exception if the member doesn't have the correct type junior
                throw new Exception(senior.FirstName + " does not meet the requirements to join this race, must be type: " + permRace);
            }
            //if the members gender isn't equal to the races gender requirement they shouldn't be able to join that race.
            else if (junior.gender != genRace)
            {
                //throws an exception if the member doesn't have the correct gender type.
                throw new Exception(junior.FirstName + " does not meet the requirements to join this race, must be a: " + genRace);
            }

            else
            {
                //if all other conditions are met, and the member meets requirements, let the member join the race and add a return date of 21 days.
                junior = jm;

                returnDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(21);
            }
        }
```

So, the problem the line occurs in is this one specifically.

```
else if (junior.memType != permRace)
            {
                //throws an exception if the member doesn't have the correct type junior
                throw new Exception(senior.FirstName + " does not meet the requirements to join this race, must be type: " + permRace);
            }
```

When the error is thrown, it gives an exception with the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an Object" instead of the exception I've ASKED it to throw. You see, I want it to throw this exception and it's right that it's doing so, but it's not providing the correct message.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: senior is probably null, doesn't have anything to do with throwing the exception, you are trying to call FirstName on an object that doesn't exist. I'm guessing it should be `junior.FirstName`, not senior.

Comment: wow, I didn't even notice that senior until you said it, must've skipped right over it and thought it was something more grand, put this as an answer, I can't believe i'm this stupid.

Comment: Also, I believe that your blocks are not correct in your `joinJunior` method. The first one (`if (junior != null)`) should likely cover more cases, as you're the doing `junior.memType != permRace` in your else-if - if you get there, it is guaranteed that `junior` is `null` (therefore, NullReferenceException)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check both primary and secondary for null situations such as

```
if ((junior == null) || (junior.memType == null))
```

Then handle an error situation per `junior` verses `junior.memType` for the `memType` is probably a true debug/development error than the known missing `junior`.